# Django restarts when changing file that does not belong to the project

Tags: django

The problem is django server is restarting when I change the `settings.py`, that does not belong to my django project.

Here is the folder structure.

```
- project
  - django-conf
    - settings.py
    - urls.py
    - ...
  - apps
    - apps1
    - ...
  - scrapy-setting
    - settings.py <------- file to be updated
```

When I update the `scrapy-setting/settings.py` django server will reload.
I don't know why.

In my django config, there is no relation to that folder.

Comment: Can you try moving scrapy-setting out of the main project folder ?

Comment: Where does that `scrapy-setting` come from?

Comment: @cezar it is a settings of scrapy

Comment: @kawadhiya21 I got it. I found that `scrapy-setting` was imported in apps1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options:

1. Use [`noreload`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-runserver-noreload) flag. **BUT** this will prevent *reload* for the whole *app*.
2. A *monkey patch* over the [`autoreload`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/autoreload.py) module, obviously not recommended.
3. **Move the external code out of the Django project**

Comment: Yes, number 3 is a golden rule! +1